# Is $.when() or $.when.apply() the correct call for getting a promise out of a forEach?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I have a function processing an array, calling a function for each entry within the array with a Promise returned, and then finally returning that it's done.

```js
var dealCardSelectableAI = function () {
  var deferred = $.Deferred();
  var deferredQueue = [];

  _.forEach(model.galaxy.systems(), function (system, starIndex) {
    if (model.canSelect(starIndex) && system.star.ai()) {
      deferredQueue.push(
        chooseCards({
          inventory: inventory,
          count: 1,
          star: system.star,
          galaxy: game.galaxy(),
          addSlot: false,
        }).then(function (result) {
          system.star.cardList(result);
        })
      );
    }
  });

  $.when.apply($, deferredQueue).then(function () {
    deferred.resolve();
  });

  return deferred.promise();
};

dealCardSelectableAI().then( /* other stuff */ )
```

Most stuff I find on promises is to do with ES6 and `Promises.all()`, but I'm working in ES5 so am using jQuery.

My understanding is that due to `deferredQueue` being of unknown length `$.when.apply()` is the correct call here rather than `$.when()`, but regardless of which I use everything seems to operate as expected.

Have I set this up correctly? Is `$.when.apply()` the correct call and am I using it right?

Comment: Yes, your code is correct. Note that `$.when()` and `$.when.apply()` are the same method, the only difference is the method of invocation. More info on what `apply()` does can be found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Comment: You could consider adding a promise library (thinking of http://bluebirdjs.com) that gives you `Promise.all`, instead of using jQuery here, but if you're dealing jQuery and jQuery deferreds *anyway*, you could just as well keep the code as it is.